# What is the difference in the behaviour of the commutator in a motor between DC and AC?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

Is it correct to say that in DC, the split ring [commutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_%28electric%29) produces direct current flow and therefore stronger voltage, as opposed to AC which produces alternating current and therefore weaker voltage?

Answer (score 0):

In DC, the split ring commutator is what allows the current in the loop (i.e. the bit inside the magnetic field) to change direction every half turn, so that the force acting on the loop always acts to turn it in the same direction. The current is direct in DC regardless of the split ring commutator.
The AC motor has alternating current, but I'm not sure that you can say there is therefore a  weaker voltage. 
Each type has its own advantages and disadvantages, and they differ in their construction but the overall effect is still to use a magnetic field and a current to generate circular motion.

Comment: If the power provided remains constant, wouldn't DC have a stronger voltage?

Comment: I think that your concept of stronger/weaker voltage is incorrect. Do you ask if there is more power used for the motor? ( $U\cdot I$ ).

Comment: I am talking about generators here, not motors - sorry for confusion. If both have the same power provided from a constant source, would DC have a stronger voltage?